# I updated to MariaDB 10.2.20 to use CTE. Still getting "Unrecognized Statement type. (near WITH) in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, common-table-expression

I am wanting to use CTE so I updated to MariaDB 10.2.20.  phpMyAdmin is giving an error on the use of "WITH".

[image: Query]

[image: MariaDB Version]

[image]

I am not able to find why "WITH" is not supported in this version.

MariaDB starting with 10.2.1¶
Common Table Expression WITH was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1.

MariaDB starting with 10.2.2
Recursive WITH has been supported since MariaDB 10.2.2.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/

Comment: Why does it say "SQL Server"?  That is not MariaDB.

Comment: It was a simple sql query.  Could have called it anything.  

SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in phpMyAdmin, see this open bug since August 2017: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13616

Comment: I did see that but as you mentioned it has been over a year and from their phpMyAdmin version: 4.7.4 to my 4.8.3 you would think this would have been addressed.  CTE is not that new.